# How to get kernel details from img file

Tags: linux-kernel

On a given linux system, I can easily find kernel information using `uname -a`, which tells me the version number, the architecture, date of build, etc of the currently loaded kernel.

How can I find similar data from a given kernel file (img) which is found in the /boot directory?  Is there the equivalent command that I can run to output the same metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` utility will provide some information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux vm 5.4.38-gentoo #1 SMP Tue May 5 00:53:31 EDT 2020 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

$ file /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.38-gentoo
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.38-gentoo: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 5.4.38-gentoo (root@vm) #1 SMP Tue May 5 00:53:31 EDT 2020, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x9, Normal VGA
```

The hardware information you can get from other sources, for instance `/proc/cpuinfo`

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo| grep "model name"
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried the `file` command, but had accidentally pointed to the wrong kernel file, and consequently didn't have the info I was expecting.  You're answer put me in the right direction.